# how I get amplitude of sound

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

I am working with android. I am trying to record sound using MediaRecorder. But now I want to calculate the amplitude of recorded sound. How I calculate it? Have any api to calculate ?any idea..

Comment: Be a bit more precise. Do you want to show the waveform after you recorded it? Or do you want to visualize the current amplitude/energy while recording similar to a V-U-meter.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an Android developer but as far as I'm concerned you would have to engage fast fourier transform in order to get a pitch of the sound. Unless, of course the sound isn't a perfect sine wave

Comment: may be android has some api to find out the max amplitude but i can't properly use it .

Comment: I always have the feeling that many people see the FFT as the solution for everything. No, this far to heavy for that simple task. Besides from that, it was asked for amplitude not pitch.